# VSCode using wrong python path when moving to another workstation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am trying to make my projects portable because of me working either at my Home PC or Work Laptop.
Everything was working fine at my home pc. I moved the project onto a portable drive, aswell as my portable vscode installation (all settings etc in "Data"-Folder).

At my work pc, I could execute my code like normal, but when I wanted to pack my program into an exe file with the installed pyinstaller in the venv, it tries to use my Home-PC python path. However, it uses the correct path to look for pyinstaller.

```
(venv) PS U:\Programming\Private Projects\in process\Twitter Bot> pyinstaller TwitterBots.py
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"e:\desktop\portable files\programming\private projects\in process\twitter bot\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "U:\Programming\Private Projects\in process\Twitter Bot\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" TwitterBots.py': Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

Home-PC-Python-Path:
`e:\desktop\portable files\programming\private projects\in process\twitter bot\venv\scripts\python.exe`

Work-PC/Portable Drive-Python-Path:
`U:\Programming\Private Projects\in process\Twitter Bot\venv\Scripts\python.exe`

Is there any way to change this whenever I switch stations? What exactly is trying to use the wrong path here, so I know where to look?

Comment: VS Code doesn't look for anything, it uses the configured Python environment. What you posted is a shell command line, not a VS Code window. Perhaps the environment is mixed up? Or your scripts have hard-coded references to the home PC's folders?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im excecuting though the terminal in VSCode. Thats what im trying to figure out. Maybe venv has the reference to my home PC`s folders hardcoded at creation? Because the venv was created on my Home-PC. But isnt that what a venv is for, a "virtual enviroment", so It wouldnt make sense to hardcode something like that in at creation? I really have no idea where the shell gets this path from.

Comment: Virtual as in a set of folders you can switch between, not as a virtual machine. You can have *many* Python environments on the same machine - one to run Anaconda, another to run Python 2, another to run the latest Python 3 version etc. If you use an environment created on your home PC it will contain paths to your home PC's folder.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new environment and switching to that?

Comment: I see that some directories in ur Home PC path begin with uppercase letter  but in ur Work PC path they begin with lowercase letter. is it a typos?

Comment: @CYREX No, this was directly copied from the shell. Now that you have pointed it out, I find it weird aswell.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I realize it is not a virtual machine, but I still thought it would make it so that the project is basically portable across pcs, as all needed resources are in the venv folder. Apparently not. When creating a new venv, everything works. I will probably create two venvs in every project folder, one for my Home PC, the other for my work pc, and switch accordingly when switching between them,. This should work and solves my problem of making my projects portable, thank you.

Comment: so its clearly that the main issue is ur venv is EXECUTING  Home PC path in ur work PC which for sure will leads to error. To not dive too much into it, i suggest to make another same config venv in ur work PC to save lots of headaches.

Comment: @Elekam or just *don't* include the environment in your version control. That's what caused the problem in the first place. Use a different environment on each machine, with the same name for convenience.

Comment: or in ur work PC, try to find the path of python.exe and copy paste in vs code **view** > **Command Palette** > **Python: Select Interpreter** >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my error was assuming that the enviroment is portable, which it isn't, and does not make much sense in the first place. At creation the enviroment saves the path to the python exe, so when that path is different on another workstation, of course it does not work.

Like @Panagiotis Kanavos answered:
I should have a different enviroment, preferably with the same name, on every workstation. These enviroments should not be included in version control.
This works as it should.